# Display Message on page after form submitted

Tags: javascript

I have a form with 2 fields (for this example) which I validate using JavaScript and if the fields contain data, the form will submit when user clicks the Submit button. I am using an iframe in the form tag to send the output to the same page.

What I would like to do is to have a message display below the form saying "Thank you for your submission". I am having difficulty trying to figure this part out.

```js
function SubmitRentalForm()
{
 var bValid    = true;
 var sFirst     = document.getElementById("fname").value;
 var sLast     = document.getElementById("lname").value;
 
 if  ( (sFirst.trim() == "")   || (sLast.trim() == "") )
 {
         bValid = false;
         return bValid;
 }

 return bValid;
}
```

```html
  <div class="main">
      <form name="RentalForm" action="email-rental.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return SubmitRentalForm()" target="myFrame">

      <table id="form_corners_rental" border="0" cellspacing="5">
      <tr>
 <td>First Name</td>
 <td><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" size="50" maxlength="60" placeholder="Enter First Name"  onblur="ValidateField(name)" />
 <span id="errorname" style="font-size:9px;color:darkred;"></span>
 </td>

 <td>Last Name</td>
 <td><input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" size="50" maxlength="60"  placeholder="Enter Last Name"  onblur="ValidateField(name)"  /></td>
       </tr></table>

     <div id="Msg" style="display:none">
      Thank you for your form submission.
      </div> 

     <br/><br/>
     <input id="submit-btn-rental"  type="submit" value="Rent Now">
      </form>
</div>

<iframe name="myFrame" width="1" height="1" style="border:none"></iframe>
```

I have added in a div tag, but am not sure how to do this.

Could someone please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Are you wanting to know how to show the div id="Msg", or are you asking how to wait to show the div until after the submission finishes, or are you asking how to do both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```js
function submitForm() {
    if(checkFieldsValidation()) {
        document.getElementById("Msg").style.display = "inline-block";
    }
}

function checkFieldsValidation() {
 var sFirst     = document.getElementById("fname").value;
 var sLast     = document.getElementById("lname").value;
 
 if  ( (sFirst.trim() == "")   || (sLast.trim() == "") ) {
         return false;
 }
 return true;
}
```

```html
  <div class="main">
      <form name="RentalForm" action="email-rental.php" method="POST" onsubmit="submitForm()" target="myFrame">

      <table id="form_corners_rental" border="0" cellspacing="5">
      <tr>
 <td>First Name</td>
 <td><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" size="50" maxlength="60" placeholder="Enter First Name"  onblur="ValidateField(name)" />
 <span id="errorname" style="font-size:9px;color:darkred;"></span>
 </td>

 <td>Last Name</td>
 <td><input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" size="50" maxlength="60"  placeholder="Enter Last Name"  onblur="ValidateField(name)"  /></td>
       </tr></table>

     <div id="Msg" style="display:none">
      Thank you for your form submission.
      </div> 

     <br/><br/>
     <input id="submit-btn-rental"  type="submit" value="Rent Now">
      </form>
</div>

<iframe name="myFrame" width="1" height="1" style="border:none"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply change the style of the msg div when the form is submited

```js
function SubmitRentalForm()
{
  var msg =document.getElementById("Msg")
 var bValid    = true;
 var sFirst     = document.getElementById("fname").value;
 var sLast     = document.getElementById("lname").value;
 
 if  ( (sFirst.trim() == "")   || (sLast.trim() == "") )
 {
         bValid = false;
         return bValid;
 }
   msg.style.display="inline-block"
 return bValid;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
      <form name="RentalForm" action="email-rental.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return SubmitRentalForm()" target="myFrame">

      <table id="form_corners_rental" border="0" cellspacing="5">
      <tr>
 <td>First Name</td>
 <td><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" size="50" maxlength="60" placeholder="Enter First Name"  />
 <span id="errorname" style="font-size:9px;color:darkred;"></span>
 </td>

 <td>Last Name</td>
 <td><input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" size="50" maxlength="60"  placeholder="Enter Last Name"  /></td>
       </tr></table>

     <div id="Msg" style="display:none">
      Thank you for your form submission.
      </div> 

     <br/><br/>
     <input id="submit-btn-rental"  type="submit" value="Rent Now">
      </form>
</div>

<iframe name="myFrame" width="1" height="1" style="border:none"></iframe>
```